# What is com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I wanted to know what does it mean, and why it is used in code:

```
com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin
```

I have one source code where:

```
<plugin identifier = "com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version = "3746" />
```

has been used. Why do we use it?

Answer (score 2):

That plugin identifier tells Xcode that any Interface Builder Document (Storyboard or XIB) was built with Xcode, and the specific version of Xcode/Interface Builder that the interface was created with.

Comment: Hey thnaks! Do IBCocoaTouchPlugin contains any license like Apple License or any other, Is this dependency is open source and can be used freely?

Comment: @SetuSharma Interface Builder is proprietary to Apple and closed-source. It was originally part of Project Builder and later integrated into Xcode: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_Builder

Comment: Should we commit this then?